# Javascript equivalent of php's parse_url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, phpjs

I am writing a chrome extension that change part of the url in the current tab and reload the page with the modified url. I am wondering if there is a Javascript equivalent of the php's parse_url function. Currently, I have to write my own parser with regex to extract parts of the url; however, I would think that such function already exists in the in Javascript.

After researching for a bit, I believe I can get a location object with "window.location" and extracts the different components with "window.location.protocal" etc...

In chrome extension, however, calls to "window.location" would to return a url which I believe refers to the internal component of chrome instead of the page's url. Assuming I that get a reference to the "tab" object in chrome, I can access the tab's url **string** with tab.url. Since tab.url is just a string, I am hoping there is an internal method that can dissect the url for me instead of writing a custom function.

Thank you

Comment: Why the google-chrome-extention tag ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url:485

Comment: Wow - didn't know about php.JS

Comment: isnt it Great ? Some purists complain but I find it a fine idea to reduce my memory load !

Answer (score 0):

In content scripts of chrome externsion `window.location` refers to page url